# How to play with the time frame of SMA on pine scrip?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to code a strategy that include {`SMA`} with different time frames than the chart I am using.

The problem is that the Parenthesis there is only "source" and "length" and no time frame. Does any one know a way to fix it?

The meta reason I am asking that is because my strategy react in the time frame of the chart and I want it to react fast but the {`SMA`} to stay slow. So if someone has something to say about it will be grate.

Thank :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still struggling with this?
From what I can see, the latest version of TradingView/MovingAverage includes a "resolution" argument. Here is the code directly from the Moving Average indicator:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Moving Average", shorttitle="MA", overlay=true, resolution="")
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset)
```

Implementing the "resolution" argument gives you the option to choose the timeframe.

Comment: thank you, actually i didn't thought on writing the SMA code and i just used the built in function.

Comment: Correction: I checked what you proposed but it’s available only on studies but not on strategies.